# Nothing happend after running test in C# NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nuget, nunit

at the beginning I want to tell you I'm new in C# automation testing.

I created NUnit Test Project (.NET Core) and I have problem with running test in C# NUnit. When I click on "Run selected test" in Test Explorer then nothing happens. I don't have any error in my Test Explorer. In output I have error **System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path**.

Additionally when I try to run test from commandline ("C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net35\nunit3-console.exe" C:\Users\MY_USER\source\repos\NUnitTestProject2\NUnitTestProject2.sln) I have 
**Could not load file or assembly nunit.framework** error.

The only way to run the test is commandline and 
**dotnet test C:\Users\MY_USER\source\repos\NUnitTestProject2\NUnitTestProject2\NUnitTestProject2.csproj**

My NuGet Dependencies:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk(15.5.0)
- NUnit (3.9.0)
- NUnit3TestAdapter (3.9.0)
- Selenium.WebDriver (3.141.0)

All the time my Test Explorer looks like this:

[image: Test Explorer screenshot]

I tried to change version of my NuGet dependencies.

```cs
 public class Tests
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver("C:/Users/MY_USER/source/repos/NUnitTestProject1/NUnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/");
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's saying you have illegal characters in your path likely just need `new ChromeDriver(@"....`  and use backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: Your ChromeDriver path refers to NUnitTestProject1 and your command lines refer to NUnitTestProject2. Did you delete NUnitTestProject1 and start over or something like that? Also I would replace the slashes with backslashes.

Comment: Nothing changed.. `driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\MY_USER\source\repos\NUnitTestProject1\NUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\");`. I tried \ and \\
EDIT:
It doesn't matter where I put chromedrive.exe. I have the same error all the time.

Comment: Another option might be to upgrade NUnit to the latest version. [Here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2898) is an issue with illegal characters in the path that seems to affect the version you are using and it was fixed in 3.11. Also maybe its worth separating this entirely from selenium. Can you run tests with no dependency on selenium?

Comment: I updated NUnit to 3.12.0 version and issue still occurs. I can't run test without selenium dependency. Additionally when I delete path from new ChromeDriver()  problem is the same https://imgur.com/MY2yIEJ

Comment: I tend to use xUnit, but I thought with NUnit you need to make the class with [TestFixture]

Comment: I added [TestFixture] before class and nothing changed..

Comment: The issue with running .NET Core tests with `nunit3-console.exe` is entirely predictable, as the console runner [does not yet support .NET Core tests](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/475).

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a `StartChromeDriver()` method to handle starting ChromeDriver correctly. Here's an example:

```
public IWebDriver StartChromeDriver()
{
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox")       
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            return driver;
}
```

Then replace the `driver = new ChromeDriver` call in your `[SetUp]` method with `driver = StartChromeDriver()`.
The issue may be that you are not providing any ChromeOptions() when initializing your ChromeDriver instance.

Also, as recommended by another user, I would write a simple test to isolate the issue from Selenium vs. NUnit. You can do so like this:

```
 public class Tests
    {
        // comment out setup method so this Selenium code does not get run.
       // IWebDriver driver;
     //   [SetUp] 
    //    public void Setup()
    //    {
    //        driver = new //ChromeDriver("C:/Users/MY_USER/source/repos/NUnitTestProject1/NUnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/");
  //      }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass("Passed first test successfully.");
        }
    }
```

If your test successfully runs without the Selenium / ChromeDriver code, then you know the issue is with Selenium and not NUnit.